# vmWare HA Admission Control configuration

Tags: vmware-esxi, high-availability

In an HA cluster of 5 hosts (100GB memory) if Admission control is enabled and %age cluster failover option is set at 25 % (lets consider only for memory ie. 125 GB), and if one host fails then the next memory failover capacity for remaining 4 hosts will become 100 GB. Correct ? 
But actually if we see, we need more failover capacity if a host fails in order to ensure that all VMs will get powered on if second host fails.

Not sure if i am correct. Please can anyone explain.

Answer (score 2):

If a host fails it will still be part of the cluster, just not available - so the percentage available equation will not change.  It would only change if you removed the host from the cluster configuration.

To really get into HA cluster sizing and host failover capacity you need to have a solid handle on slot sizes and reservations used in the environment.  There are tons of great articles out on the net on the topic.